# Problems with Installing packages - Ubuntu 16.04 TLS

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm new to Ubuntu, and am having trouble installing some packages on 16.04 TLS. The first one is pip. When I ran `sudo apt-get install python-pip`, I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpcl1.7 : Depends: libpcl-people1.7 but it is not going to be installed
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried the command with the `-f` flag but still it didn't help. 
I then tried to install libpcl-people1.7 using `sudo apt-get install libpcl-people1.7`, but I got even more errors:

```
After this operation, 74.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcl-people1.7_1.7.2-14build1_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: Interrupted system call
(Reading database ... 283158 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcl-people1.7_1.7.2-14build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcl-people1.7:amd64 (1.7.2-14build1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/var/cache/apt/archives/libpcl-people1.7_1.7.2-14build1_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: failed to read (Input/output error)
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpcl-people1.7_1.7.2-14build1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
                                                                                     Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpcl-people1.7_1.7.2-14build1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have updated the system before I ran these commands. To me the errors just look weird. What might be the cause for these errors? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `apt-get clean`, `apt-get check` and checking the filesystem permissions?

Comment: `E: Read error - read (5: Input/output error)` – uh oh… looks like your storage drive may be failing. Could you please refer to [How do I check the integrity of a storage medium (hard disk or flash drive)?](/q/539184/175814) to either confirm or refute that? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! Having run apt-get clean and apt-get check I'm now able to install the packages. I also checked my hard disk as suggested by David, and found that my disk is failing :( . I think I'll get a new one.